# Uploading an array of tuples Cloud Kit

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, cloudkit

I am trying to upload an array of tuples to CloudKit. I am continually getting a Bad_Instruction error. The error is on the line } as! (CKRecord?, Error?) -> Void)

```
let newTA = CKRecord(recordType: "Terms")
            newTA["terms"] = terms as CKRecordValue?
            var publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
            publicData.save(newTA, completionHandler: {(record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?)-> Void in
                if error == nil{

                    print("TA Saved")
                }
                else{

                }
                } as! (CKRecord?, Error?) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your save line should probably be more like this

```
publicData.save(newTA, completionHandler: {(record, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil{
        print("TA Saved")
    }
    else{

    }
})
```